# PowerShell script for Active Directory and permissions

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, administrator, memberof

I am writing a PowerShell script that extracts users from a specific OU and their group membership, puts the results in a CSV file and then emails that CSV file to specified recipients.

The script works fine, but I face the following problem:
When I run the script from my domain controller, from a PowerShell console running under my account (which is part of the domain administrators) the CSV file that gets generated has only the usernames and the group membership is empty.

If I run it from an elevated prompt then it works fine and the membership information is included in the CSV file.

See script below:

```
import-module ActiveDirectory

##############################
# Start Configuration Section#
##############################
$customer = 'customername'
$sender = 'sender@email.com'
$recipient = 'recipient@email.com'
$recipient_cc = 'cc@email.com'
$recipient_bcc = 'bcc@email.com'
$subject = 'Subject'
$body = ''
$smtpserver = "127.0.0.0"
$searchbase = "OU=" + $customer + ",OU=SomeOtherOu,DC=Example,DC=com"
############################
# End Configuration Section#
############################

$csvfile = 'D:\Scripts\ActiveDirectoryExports\' + $customer + '.csv'

$users | foreach {Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(objectclass=person)' -SearchBase $searchbase -Properties displayname,memberof} | select-object displayname,@{name='memberof';expression=    {$_.memberof -join ';'}} | export-csv $csvfile -NoTypeInformation

$att = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($csvfile)
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg.From = $sender
$msg.To.Add($recipient)
$msg.Cc.Add($recipient_cc)
$msg.Bcc.Add($recipient_bcc)
$msg.Subject = $subject
$msg.Body = $body
$msg.Attachments.Add($att)
$smtp.Send($msg)
$att.Dispose()

remove-item $csvfile
```

Any ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: Where is $users coming from?

Comment: I'm assuming this isn't the exact script you are using. Even if you are somehow defining $Users before you run the script, why would you run it against a ForEach loop and then never use `$_` in it? It makes more sense to do `$Users | Get-ADUser -FiltersAndStuff | Select Properties | Export-CSV File.csv -NoType`

Comment: When you created the task, did you check the box that says "Run with highest privileges"?

Comment: about the @users variable indeed it is not used, it was something I took from another script and never looked at closely.
Do you think this could be causing the issue though? If it was the case I would expect that it wouldnt work when i run it at an elevated prompt as well.
Colyn, I havent added this to a scheduled task , I am trying to run it from a powershell console for a start